# How to get the last word from a URL?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a method to extract just the last word from the URL example below? I would like to be able to use this as a heading on a page, i.e the "Account" page.

I found that by using `request.path` it will give me the path without the root but I'm not sure how to get just the last path name.

```
/users/1234/account
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
request.path.split('/').last
```

If you want "Account" (instead of "account"), call the `capitalize` method on the result.

Comment: (request.path.split('/').last).capitalize: This was what I used, and it's exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Ruby, but you can try this approach.

Try string splitting request.path with '/' as the separator and take the last element from the resulting array

users/1234/account will be split to `{'user', '1234', 'account'}`

Even though this doesn't answer your question directly, I hope it gives you a start

Comment: That's not proper array nomenclature in Ruby. Use `['user', '1234', 'account']` instead.

Answer (score 1):

URLs are a simple string consisting of a scheme showing how to connect to a site, the host where the resource is located, plus a path to that resource. You can use [`File.basename`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-basename) to get the last part of that path, just like we'd use on a file on our disk:

```
File.basename('/users/1234/account')
=> "account"
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have URL like `https://www.google.com/user/lastword`

If you want to store last word of the URL which is `lastword` in a variable then use the following and pass url as value to `finalVal`.

`var getLastWordFromUrl = finalVal.split("/").last()`

Comment: Please expand on your answer.

Comment: Hope you get it now!!